# Json formatted object to simple array with new key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a object like this:

```
{
            "ABC":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},
            "XYZ":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},
            "PQR":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},
            "overall":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5}
}
```

I am trying to make a simple array like this

```
[
            ["type":"ABC","minValue":0,"maxValue":5],
            ["type":"XYZ","minValue":0,"maxValue":5],
            ["type":"PQR","minValue":0,"maxValue":5],
            ["type":"overall","minValue":0,"maxValue":5]
]
```

> not getting idea how to get it.

Here is my attempt:

```
var s = scoreFilters;  //my json object
    var out = Object.keys(s).map(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        return [["type":data,"minValue":data.minValue,"maxValue":data.maxValue]];
    });
```

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: my expected out put is array. i think its possible

Comment: I think `["type":"ABC","minValue":0,"maxValue":5]` should be `{"type":"ABC","minValue":0,"maxValue":5}`

Comment: Yes Senal is right. You can't have a array with key value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want an array of objects for your output, you can `.map` the `Object.entries` of your input:

```js
const obj = {
  "ABC":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},
  "XYZ":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},
  "PQR":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},
  "overall":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5}
};
const arr = Object.entries(obj).map(([type, { minValue, maxValue }]) => ({
  type,
  minValue,
  maxValue
}));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```js
let input = {"ABC":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},"XYZ":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},"PQR":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5},"overall":{"minValue":0,"maxValue":5}}

let output = Object.entries(input).map(([type, values]) => ({ type, ...values}))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` and `.map()` to get an array of objects:

```js
const data = {
  "ABC": {"minValue": 0,"maxValue": 5},
  "XYZ": {"minValue": 0,"maxValue": 5},
  "PQR": {"minValue": 0,"maxValue": 5},
  "overall": {"minValue": 0,"maxValue": 5}
};

const result = Object.entries(data)
                     .map(([ k, v ]) => Object.assign({}, {type: k},  v));
                     
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```